# How to implement implementations in android without error?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, implementation, androidx

I want to add AdView to my activity and I click on download and then it automatically implements the necessary library. But then I get the following error:
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrONg.png)

I get the same error when I try to add GridLayout to my library.

Here is my gradle file: [gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk786.png)

I already tried to set the Global Gradle settings to offline work but it doesn't help.

I have android studio 3.4.2

This is a problem that bothers me for a while now and there seems no solution to this. Is it possible that these things are not available for androidx yet? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

To make the Google Play services APIs available to your app:

> Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
>   Note: Android Studio projects contain a top-level build.gradle file and a build.gradle file for each module. Be sure to edit the file for your application module. See Building Your Project with Gradle for more information about Gradle.
>   Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services, using one of the APIs listed below.
>   **Ensure that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to the google() repo or to maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }.**
>   Save the changes, and click Sync Project with Gradle Files in the toolbar.
>   You can now begin developing features with the Google Play services APIs.

This is often a common mistake. If you have multiple repositories in your gradle, make sure that maven google is at the top of the list.

eg.

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This package:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1"
```

is either available from repository `google()` or from repository `mavenCentral()`:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    ...
}
```

see the [quick-start](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).